# Error in IE when looping

Tags: javascript, arrays

Lets clarify my question,

I want to make an element which the element contains 5 fields so I dont want the user should be able to put in a new element if the old one is null, so I made the alert when looping through the old element and see if there is some strings, if not then dont put a new element and make an alert please fill out all fields

Here again my code

```
function addEvent() {
      var ni = document.getElementById('discount'); // Takes the a div named discount
      var discountForm = document.getElementById('discountForm'); // Takes the a form named discountForm
      var numi = document.getElementById('theValue'); // Takes the a hidden input field named theValue
      var num = (document.getElementById("theValue").value -1)+ 2; // Start counting to set the new divs form numbers
      numi.value = num;
      var divIdName = "my"+num+"Div"; // the new divs will be named
      var allDivTags = discountForm.getElementsByTagName('div'); // take all div tags
      var numOfDivs = (allDivTags.length -1); // take the number of the old div
      var oldDivIdName = document.getElementById(allDivTags[numOfDivs].id); // old div id
      var newdiv = document.createElement('div'); //the new div
      newdiv.setAttribute("id",divIdName);
      newdiv.innerHTML = "Company <select name=\"company[]\"><option value=\"\"></option><option value=\"ZI\">Avis</option><option value=\"ET\">Enterprise</option><option value=\"ZE\">Hertz</option><option value=\"ZD\">Budget</option><option value=\"ZR\">National</option><option value=\"AL\">Alamo</option></select> Discount Type <select name=\"type[]\"><option value=\"CD\">Discount Number</option><option value=\"PC\">Coupon Number</option></select> Code <input name=\"code[]\" type=\"text\"> Title <input name=\"title[]\" type=\"text\"> <a href=\"javascript:;\" onclick=\"removeElement(\'"+divIdName+"\')\">Remove</a>"; // creating the fileds in the new div
      ni.appendChild(newdiv);
      for(i=0; i<discountForm.elements.length;i++){ // loop through the divs
          if(numOfDivs != i-1){ // if tho old div exist and if the old div fields are empty
            if(oldDivIdName.children[i].value.length == 0){
              removeElement(divIdName); // then dont put the new one
              alert('Please enter all fields');
            }
          }
      }

    }
```

But my problem is that in IE comes out an error `children[...].value.length is null or not an object` so I trying to figure how to fix it,

I hope its more clearly for you now.

Comment: Where is numOfDivs originally set, or what is its purpose?

Comment: Post more relevant code.

Comment: numOfDivs counts how many divs its in a form

Comment: Why you are using `var numOfDivs = (allDivTags.length -1);`, if 5 divs exists then it'll assign 4 in to `numOfDivs`

Comment: Really not clear what you're trying to do here. Please don't make the volunteers here try to guess what you are doing. Instead, use code comments to explain what is happening at each point and then where the problem is occurring.

Comment: Don't know where you problem is...but you're not declaring variable `i` so it's global and this might lead to problems. Also, I suggest you use `===` and `!==`. Then `length` is falsy, no need to compare to `0`

Comment: Yes, thats what I want because I want to catch the old div, look the next one `var oldDivIdName = document.getElementById(allDivTags[numOfDivs].id);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very hard to tell from the information you've given us. But my first guess is the following:

```
for(i=0; i<discountForm.elements.length;i++){
  if(numOfDivs != i-1){
    if(oldDivIdName.children[i].value.length == 0){
      removeElement(divIdName);
      alert('Please enter all fields');
    }
  }
}
```

Above you're doing:

```
oldDivIdName.children[i]
```

But i is defined as the number of elements in the form from what I can see... not the number of children of the oldDivIdName. If there are more elements in the form than there are in oldDivIdName then the value of oldDivIdName.children[i] will be null. And "value" is not defined on null.

Comment: I just updated my question please see if its more clearly for you now, thanks for you time

Answer (score 0):

It's very hard to tell from the information you've given us. But my first guess is the following:

When  you first call this method, allDivTags.length whether is null or negative, and results
not got element:

```
var oldDivIdName = document.getElementById(allDivTags[numOfDivs].id);
```